# Sending data from Table Storage to Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-eventhub

It happens so the systems we have to work with has immutable `Batch` layer as `Table Storage`. We would like to forward new records added to `Table Storage` to be sent to `Event Hub` so that we can process further.

1. Is there a way to continuously write new records written to `Table Storage` to be written to `Event Hub`?
2. Is it possible otherwise to use either Python or Java SDK of Azure Storage to read newly added records?

Comment: I would turn it around, send data to event hub and from there to the table storage

Comment: yes that would be preferable. it is a customer setup. it would take longer for such changes to go through.

Comment: Have you looked at logic apps? There are automatic triggers for these things that you can simply configure.